# Do medals in Tricolor Battles count attacking teams separately?

Tags: splatoon-3

Let's say there's a Tricolor Battle where the attacking Green and Red teams fought against the defending Blue team.

If I'm awarded the #1 Turf Inker badge while on the Green Team, does that mean I was the #1 Inker across the attacking Green and Red team, or are the two attacking teams considered separate?

[image: Medals after a tricolor battle]